# Android NotificationCompat BigPictureStyle portrait image

Tags: android, image, push-notification, notifications, portrait

I am trying to show portrait image (1:2 aspect ratio) in my notification using [NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded). As far as I know, the recommended size that will not be cropped is 2:1, is there any way to override this behavior to show portrait sized image?

Comment: Have you tried with custom notification layout ? You can try this https://medium.com/degoo/android-creating-a-custom-notification-layout-with-an-image-or-photo-bd282637a04e